# Make создает непонятный build файл

Tags: makefile, build, avr-gcc

Здравствуйте. В самописном мейке есть такая цель:

build: $(SRC)

```
avr-gcc $(CFLAGS) $(SYMBOLS) -c $(SRC)
avr-gcc $(LDFLAGS) $(LSET) -o $(TARGET).elf $(OBJS) -lm
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .nwram $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).hex<br>
```

После make build в каталоге проекта создается непонятный build файл. Может кто пояснить что это и зачем нужно?

Comment: Ну создаётся он каким-нибудь touch'ем затем, чтобы не повторять без нужды последовательность компиляция/линковка/objcopy. Если время создания/изменения файла больше, чем время изменения $(SRC), то .elf и .hex файлы свежие и ничего делать не надо. Меньше -- пересобрать. Может несколько неуклюже, но беды в этом не вижу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, alexlz. Да, как выяснилось этот файл создавал gcc а не make, я скопипастил флаги и там были включены какие то хитрые опции.